# How to move up not null alphabetically sorted values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, order-by

I have a table like this:

```
   |Name1 |Name2 | Name3 | Name4|
   |------+------+-------+------|
   |Zoe   |NULL  |NULL   |NULL  |
   |Julia |NULL  |NULL   |NULL  |
   |NULL  |Ashley|NULL   |NULL  |
   |NULL  |Belvet|NULL   |NULL  |
   |NULL  |Maria |NULL   |NULL  |
   |NULL  |NULL  |Mark   |NULL  |
   |NULL  |NULL  |Jane   |NULL  |
   |NULL  |NULL  |NULL   |Eve   |
   |NULL  |NULL  |NULL   |Jenny |
   |NULL  |NULL  |NULL   |Ketty |
```

How can I order alphabetically every single column in a way that the NULL values are pushed on the bottom, like this:

```
   |Name1 |Name2 | Name3 | Name4|
   |------+------+-------+------|
   |Julia |Ashley|Jane   |Eve   |
   |Zoe   |Belvet|Mark   |Jenny |
   |NULL  |Maria |NULL   |Ketty |
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to want is something rather unusuarl (at least from my perspective), where the concept of *row* is no longer important, and you care only about *columns*, ignoring from which row its values came from. This is a bit tricky, because SQL understands columns together with rows. So you need, somehow, to *deconstruct* your tables and *reconstruct* them later on.

First thing we will do is have a different `table` (result of a subquery) with two columns: a `row_number()` and one `NameX`:

For every column, we will do something like:

```
-- First column
SELECT 
     @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank,
     Name1
FROM 
    t,  (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY
    -- 'zzzzzzz' = value larger than any realistically one
    -- in column Name1. Change if necessary.
    COALESCE(Name1, 'zzzzzzzzzz'),
```

... and that would result in:

```
rank | Name1
---: | :----
   1 | Julia
   2 | Zoe  
   3 | null 
   4 | null 
   5 | null 
   6 | null 
   7 | null 
   8 | null 
   9 | null 
  10 | null
```

This is one *deconstruction* (to put it a name).

---

**NOTE**: `@rownum := @rownum + 1` is equivalent to using `ROW_NUMBER()` in stanrdard SQL. See [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql). MySQL doesn't have a `row_number()` function, but lets you instead use variables in your queries (See [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  Language Structure  /  User-Defined Variables / 9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html))

---

With this in mind, we then need to do:

1. Repeat 4 times, for Name1 .. Name4, to get actually 4 (virtual) tables. We will have actually *deconstructed* the original table.
2. We have now 4 (virtual) tables with a common column (`rank`) and with the same number of rows as the original table. We `JOIN` them together on this common column.
3. We get rid of the rows that are `NULL` end to end by adding a `WHERE NOT (Name1 IS NULL AND Name2 IS NULL AND Name3 IS NULL AND Name4 IS NULL)`

The full query will then be:

```
SELECT
    Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4
FROM
    (SELECT   @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 AS rank, Name1
    FROM      t, (SELECT @rownum1 := 0) AS r1
    ORDER BY  coalesce(Name1, 'zzzzzzzzz')
    )  c1
    JOIN
    (SELECT   @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rank, Name2
    FROM      t, (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) AS r2
    ORDER BY  coalesce(Name2, 'zzzzzzzzz')
    )  c2
    ON c2.rank = c1.rank
    JOIN
    (SELECT   @rownum3 := @rownum3 + 1 AS rank, Name3
    FROM      t, (SELECT @rownum3 := 0) AS r3
    ORDER BY  coalesce(Name3, 'zzzzzzzzz')
    )  c3
    ON c3.rank = c1.rank
    JOIN
    (SELECT   @rownum4 := @rownum4 + 1 AS rank, Name4
    FROM      t, (SELECT @rownum4 := 0) AS r4
    ORDER BY  coalesce(Name4, 'zzzzzzzzz')
    )  c4
    ON c4.rank = c1.rank
WHERE
    NOT (Name1 IS NULL AND Name2 IS NULL AND Name3 IS NULL AND Name4 IS NULL)
```

And this will give you your intended result:

```
Name1 | Name2  | Name3 | Name4
:---- | :----- | :---- | :----
Julia | Ashley | Jane  | Eve  
Zoe   | Belvet | Mark  | Jenny
null  | Maria  | null  | Ketty
```

You can check everything together at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2450da1a20d01784f91ead1bb7e550de)*

---

If you're using MariaDB 10.2 or other database that knows of `WINDOW` functions, you can simplify this query to:

```
SELECT
    Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4
FROM
    (SELECT Name1, row_number() over (order by coalesce(Name1, 'zzzzzzzzz')) AS rank
    FROM t
    )  c1
    JOIN
    (SELECT Name2, row_number() over (order by coalesce(Name2, 'zzzzzzzzz')) AS rank
    FROM t
    )  c2
    ON c2.rank = c1.rank
    JOIN
    (SELECT Name3, row_number() over (order by coalesce(Name3, 'zzzzzzzzz')) AS rank
    FROM t
    )  c3
    ON c3.rank = c1.rank
    JOIN
    (SELECT Name4, row_number() over (order by coalesce(Name4, 'zzzzzzzzz')) AS rank
    FROM t
    )  c4
    ON c4.rank = c1.rank
WHERE
    NOT (Name1 IS NULL AND Name2 IS NULL AND Name3 IS NULL AND Name4 IS NULL)
```

and you will get the same result.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ad1d5d89a4bcb982d505b91667d24380)*

---

You can even play to your advantage the fact that MariaDB sorts `NULLS LAST`, and ignore the `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4
FROM
    (SELECT Name1, row_number() over (order by Name1) AS rank
    FROM t
    )  c1
    JOIN
    (SELECT Name2, row_number() over (order by Name2) AS rank
    FROM t
    )  c2
    ON c2.rank = c1.rank
    JOIN
    (SELECT Name3, row_number() over (order by Name3) AS rank
    FROM t
    )  c3
    ON c3.rank = c1.rank
    JOIN
    (SELECT Name4, row_number() over (order by Name4) AS rank
    FROM t
    )  c4
    ON c4.rank = c1.rank
WHERE
    NOT (Name1 IS NULL AND Name2 IS NULL AND Name3 IS NULL AND Name4 IS NULL);
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5ff43b34b550c1e7f0e37f89a52aa321)*

NOTE: The execution plans are identical, so the last two queries are expected to take about the same time to perform.